# Finding corresponding eigenvectors for complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to find the eigenvectors for a matrix $A$ with $\lambda_{1,2} = -1 \pm i\nu$ and I computed

\begin{equation}
A-\lambda_{1} I = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2-i\nu & \mu+\nu& \mu & \nu+2\\ 
 0 & \nu-i\nu & 0 & 2\nu\\ 
 -\mu & 2-\nu & 2-i\nu& -\mu-2\nu\\ 
 0 & -\nu& 0 & -\nu- i \nu
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Now it is given that
\begin{equation} 
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
-1\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix} + i \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
-1\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation} is  solution for row 2 and 4. **I really do not see why.** And also, how would I continue from here to find the corresponding eigenvectors?

Comment: If you write the matrix A-lambda1I as M and an eigenvector as v, you have Mv=0. For some unknown reason, the first and and third rows are deleted. Then, yes, the given v is a solution of the equation but why anyone would delete the first and third rows of M is another question entirely.

Comment: But then how would you compute the eigenvector from scratch?

Comment: Given an nxn matrix A, (i) find the expression det(lambda I-A), which is a polynomial in lambda of degree n. (ii)Solve the equation det(lambda I-A)=0. (iii) For each lambda you found in (ii), solve the system of equations (lambda I-A)v=0, or, equivalently, (A-lambda I)v=0, where v=transpose of [x1,...,xn].

Comment: Yes, I did step 1 and step 2, but I do not succeed in solving the system for $0$.

Comment: :The matrix (A-lambda I) has determinant 0 so a solution of (A-lambda I)v can be obtained by going along any row and taking co-factors. Going along the first row would not be useful because all the co-factors would be 0, since the 2nd and 4th rows are proportional. Go along the 4-th row and take co-factors. At least one of these is not zero so you have found an eigenvector. Moreover, you now know that the rank of A-lambda I is 3, so the eigenspace for that eigenvector is 1-dimensional. Since A is real,the eigenvector for the conjugate of lambda 1 is the conjute of v.